# Shrinking navigation bar when scrolling down, cross-browser compatibility issues

Tags: javascript, css, cross-browser, mozilla

From reading another post I was able to get the shrinking nav effect using the following code in Chrome:

```
$(function(){
    $('nav').data('size','big');
    $('.shrink').data('size','big');
});

$(window).scroll(function(){
    var $nav = $('nav');
    var $shrink = $('.shrink');

    if ($('body').scrollTop() > 0) {
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'big') {
            $nav.data('size','small').stop().animate({
                height:'67px'
            }, 400);
            $shrink.data('size','small').stop().animate({ 
                top: '0'
            }, 400);
        }
    } else {
        if ($nav.data('size') == 'small') {
            $nav.data('size','big').stop().animate({
                height:'90px'
            }, 400);
            $shrink.data('size','small').stop().animate({ 
                top: '1em'
            }, 400);
        }  
    }
});
```

However, I am not getting the same effect in Firefox. What should I do to make the code compatible? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Not certain why the Firefox is not generating a value for the scrollTop() but I was able to get the js to run if I also looked at the window's scrollY property.

```
if ($('body').scrollTop() > 0 || window.scrollY > 0) { ....
```